# ExpressJS 4 error middleware function is not recognized by TypeScript

Tags: typescript, express, express-4

ExpressJS error middleware functions need 4 parameters (err, req, res, next) instead of the usual 3 (res, res, next) in order to work.

```
// @ts-ignore
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

The middleware works perfectly, but as you can see, I need to add the `// @ts-ignore` comment in order to have the code compiled and avoid my editor showing the errors. This happens because in my `tsconfig.json` I have `strict: true` which includes `noImplicitAny : true`, which I want.

But as I have `"@types/express": "^4.17.21"` installed and added to my `devDependencies` on `package.json`, I don't understand why ExpressJS doesn't infer automatically the parameter types of the function the same way it does when there are only 3 parameters.

I have `"express": "^4.18.2"`, by the way.

Any ideas? Thank you.